# How to include codeigniter framework in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, codeigniter

How can I include CodeIgnitor framework when creating a new project in eclipse IDE?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a new PHP project in Eclipse. Copy the CodeIgniter files in the root of your project directory.

Eg: if your project is called "CI_Test", your directory structure should look like this (assuming you are using CodeIgniter 2.0.2):

**CI_Test**/application
**CI_Test**/system
**CI_Test**/index.php
**CI_Test**/license.txt